# Can't use internet because networkmanager has disappeared !! (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: network-manager, internet, connection

I need help, and it is quite urgent.
I had connections issues (my Wi-Fi connection kept disconnecting)

So I followed what a member of this community recommended, in a  similar post written by a fellow member

I entered  these commands  in a shell

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install network-manager 
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

And now... I don't see any wifi parameters. I can't connect to the internet...

How can I fix this?

Here is what I get when i type sudo dmesg | grep wlo1

[image]

Comment: Well, that uninstalls network-manager (breaking your network access), then tries to update the package repo, which fails due to no internet access. So... that is either missing context of plain wrong. Where did you see that?

Comment: Do you still have a wireless interface? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `iwconfig | head -3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  When  i enter your command chili555, i get :  lo no wireless extension            enx0c5..  no wireless extension     wlo1 ieee 802.11 essid off/any     mode managed  access point not associated  tx-power=0 dBm  retry  short  limit:7 rts  thr:off fragment thr:off

Comment: I remember doing that a long time ago.  Not sure now if I used the CD to install, or had to download network manager on another computer.

Comment: Besides my computer, I have two  more  devices right now  a  smartphone with an usb cable, and a usb pluggable 4g modem

Comment: Bluetooth connection of my computer is still working. Could that help?

Comment: *Could that help?* Theoretically yes. If you can connect to a Bluetooth tethered network from your smartphone it may be enough to install/reinstall what you need. But speeds will be atrocious let alone stability.

Comment: My laptop and smartphone are paired. My smartphone isbconnected to internet. What should i do to share my internet connection  to my laptop please ? Is there à command to enter ?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: What other  information  do you need guiverc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absense of Network Manager, I suggest that you use netplan. From the terminal, do:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

Find out the name of the file. Make a backup as you will need it after reinstalling NM:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/<file_you_found>.yaml /etc/netplan/<file_you_found>.bak
```

Now, let’s create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/config.yaml
```

Write the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Of course, substitute your details here. Note that the network name and password are enclosed in quotes “.

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrrl+o followed by Enter) and exit nano (Ctrl+x followed by Enter).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Did you connect?

```
iwconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

It might take a reboot.

If you are connected, reinstall NM:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install –reinstall network-manager ubuntu-desktop
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. If so, I will edit this answer to revert netplan.

**EDIT**: Now that you are connected and have reinstalled Network Manager, we should revert the netplan file to again refer to NM.

Please do:

```
 ls /etc/netplan
```

I assume that the file you backed up is /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.bak

If so, first back up the file you just created above:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/config.yaml  /etc/netplan/config.bak
```

And restore the previous file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.bak  /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Im trying

Comment: Excellent answer! +1

Comment: So i followed what you adviced  me to do. For some reason, its not working  is there a way to re  open file  that i have just created to make sure  that  i made no mistake please?

Comment: Sure, simply reopen with nano and save and exit as I outlined above.

Comment: Thanks ! I added  an extra space and now that k have fixed it, there are changes. When i type iwconfig i see my ssid name and other  information  but  i the  ping  command  is not  working

Comment: Please run and edit your question to show: `sudo dmesg | grep wlo1`

Comment: So i have taken a  picture of my screen and updated my original post to show you what i get. it would have taken too much time to type everything. Im sorry the picture is wrongly rotated

Comment: The wireless appears to be roaming from among two access points; evidently with the same name! This is typical of 2.4gHz and 5 gHz segments of a router. Is it possible to rename them to myrouter2.4 and my router5 or some such. Then you'd meed to amend the netplan file to specify which.

Comment: I have just tried with another device and its working ! THANKS A LOT. You have all my respect :')

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, I will. Really thanks Again. So i have just réinstalled  network manager but it does not detect my other wifi network which used to appear in the wifi liste :/ and the interface seems  a  bit different

Comment: Does it appear if you do: `nmcli device wifi rescan` and follow with: `nmcli device wifi list` ?

Comment: It says scanning not allowed While unavailable or activating.  By the way it seems that The  only wifi connection that I can use is the one I put in the nano file apparently

Comment: Ahhh! We need to, as I mentioned in my answer, revert the netplan file. I shall write an edit in a few moments.

Comment: THANKS A LOT CHILI555 YOU ROCK. I WISH YOU ALL THE BEST FOR THE FUTURE. TAKE CARE !!